# Canvas doesn't draw anything? Kotlin

Tags: android, canvas, kotlin, syntax, spinner

When I write this code it doesn't work:

```
 if(shapeSpinner?.selectedItemPosition == 0){
            canvas.drawCircle((0..dimensionX).random().toFloat(), (0..dimensionY).random().toFloat(), (0..dimensionX).random().toFloat(), paint)
 }
 if(shapeSpinner?.selectedItemPosition == 1){
            canvas.drawRect((0..dimensionX).random().toFloat(), (0..dimensionY).random().toFloat(), (0..dimensionX).random().toFloat(), (0..dimensionY).random().toFloat(), paint)
 }
```

But when I write this code it works:

```
 canvas.drawCircle((0..dimensionX).random().toFloat(), (0..dimensionY).random().toFloat(), (0..dimensionX).random().toFloat(), paint)
```

But I want the user to be able to choose which shape they want to draw.
Why doesn't the first code work?

Comment: Is anything selected in the spinner at the time of execution of the drawing code? Maybe you just need to move it into the onSelectionChange listener?

Comment: Thank's, it worked.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer. Please mark it as resolved so the question doesn't stand unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is anything selected in the spinner at the time of execution of the drawing code? Maybe you just need to move it into the `onSelectionChange` listener?